# Setting the System Masterpage in SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, system-master-page

I want to set the Masterpage for System pages (eg, /_layouts/15/Settings.aspx) on a SharePoint Foundation 2013 site to a masterpage that is different than the default masterpage being used by the normal site pages.

I have set the MasterpageUrl property on the SiteCollection but that has made this masterpage also apply to System pages.

This is a SharePoint Foundation 2013 site, so I do not have access to Publishing Features or other Server specific features.  I do have access to PowerShell and/or creating custom solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the masterpages with Powershell. Taken from [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/11081/site-master-page-vs-system-master-page-or-custommasterurl-vs.aspx):

**All pages, except for publishing pages** (which you do not have in Foundation) uses the **system master**.

For system master page:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://localhost/ 
$web.MasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/mymasterpagename.master" 
$web.Update()
```

For publishing pages master page:

> Site Master page
>
> This master page is used by all publishing pages in a site, so when we
>   are working with publishing pages update this master pages.This is
>   available as a property of the object SPWeb , you could access like
>   SPWeb.CustomMasterUrl

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://localhost 
$web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/mymasterpagename.master" 
$web.Update()
```

Just make sure that the paths to your masterpage is entered correct

Comment: I have already set the MasterUrl, which has applied the masterpage to ALL pages including the System pages.  The CustomMasterUrl does not appear to affect any of the pages on the site.  I think that I read that it is for Publishing pages only, which is not a feature of SharePoint Foundation.

Comment: Exactly, as I also written above. You got one master for publishing pages, and one for all other pages

Comment: Updated the answer to clarify

Comment: Ok but my inquiry is how to have a different masterpage for the System pages from all the other pages on my site.  You could do this for older versions of SP.  Is it possible for SPF 2013?